# SQL: calculate if a period between 2 dates equal or less than 3 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Would you help me, please, to write a T-SQL query which calculates if a period between 2 dates equal or less than 3 months.

Calculation logic: if the first date = 4 April, then 4 July is the last day, then the statement 'equal_or_less_than_3_months' is true.

Exception: if the first date = 31 August, then 30 November is the last day, then the statement 'equal_or_less_than_3_months' is true.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  E.g., [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Considering the constraints, seems like what you *actually* want is `DATEADD`.

Comment: pilcrow, Larnu, thank you very much for the quick response. I tried dateadd(month, -3, dt) and that worked fine. E.g. for dates: May 29, 30, 31, dateadd returned: February 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
WHERE END_DATE < DATEADD(month,  3, BEGIN_DATE)
```